# Category Page Displaying all Pages

Tags: php, categories, pages, query

My page here: https://blackfreedom.proquest.com/category/civil-rights-and-black-power-movements/activism/selma-demonstrations-and-marches/

is displaying all pages on the site, not just the ones that are associated with this 'Selma' category. Which piece am i missing? Should I be using WP_query instead? I'd like to have this dynamic so that all of category pages show the correct pages associated with their cats.

Putting this in my archive.php code:

```
<ul>

   <?php
        $cat = get_query_var('cat');
        $PozCat = get_category ($this_category);
        $PozCat->id;
        query_posts('&post_type=page”.'.$PozCat->id);
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <p> <?php the_excerpt()?> </p>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$this_category` is not defined; try working with: `$PozCat = get_category ($cat);`

Comment: Interesting. It's now showing the pages, but only ones that are not associated with the current category.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using this:

```
<div>
            <ul>
            
            <?php 
            $current_category = get_queried_object(); ////getting current category
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',// your post type,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'cat' => $current_category->cat_ID // current category ID
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if($the_query->have_posts()):
   while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<h2><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
    "<p>".the_excerpt()."</p>";
endwhile;
endif;
            ?>
            </ul>
                </div>
```